# Flexbox. elements not aligned on the same height

Tags: css, flexbox

I created a wrapper element that contains 2 inline-block boxes next to each other (aqua and yellow in the picture). Then I created another two div both nested in one of the inline-blocks to center the content. It works but for some reason the vertical position of my flexbox is moved down even though I do not use any margin, padding or absolute positioning. If anyone has any idea why this happens, please enlighten me! I would really appreciate it.

The visual representation:

[image]

HTML code:

```
  <section className="summary">
                <div className="summary-wrapper">

                    <div className="user-wrapper">
                        <div className="user-wrapper__photo">
                            <div className="user-wrapper__photo-avatar">
                                test
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="user-wrapper__userInfo">
                            <div className="user-wrapper__userInfo-text">
                                <div>Rodney Wormsbecher</div>
                                <div>Software developer</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </section>
```

The SCSS code:

```
.summary {
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0% 100%);
    padding: 40px;
    color: white;

    &-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 8rem;
        // background: red;
    }

    & .user-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20rem;
        height: 5rem;
        background: yellow;

        &__photo {
            display: inline-block;
            background:  aqua;

            &-avatar {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                background: pink;
                height: 5rem;
                width: 5rem;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

        }

        &__userInfo {
           display: inline-block;

           &-text {
            display: flex;
            padding-left: 1.5rem;
            height: 5rem;
            width: 15rem;
            align-items: flex-start;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content:  center;

           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve] with the rendered css

Comment: I'll try it's a react application, so need to work out some things.

Comment: Provided. note that  I included my css reset as well.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqpYNe

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the boxes with display: inline-block needed a 'vertical-align: top' property. Then I had to realign the flexbox item.

Updated SCSS:

```
.summary {
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0% 100%);
    padding: 40px;
    color: white;

    &-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 8rem;
        // background: red;
    }

    & .user-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20rem;
        height: 5rem;
        background: aqua;
        vertical-align: top;

        &__photo {
            display: inline-block;

            &-avatar {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                background: pink;
                height: 5rem;
                width: 5rem;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

        }

        &__userInfo {
           display: inline-block;
           vertical-align: top;

           &-text {
            display: flex;
            padding-left: 1.5rem;
            height: 5rem;
            width: 15rem;
            align-items: flex-start;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: yellow;
            justify-content: center;
           }
        }
    }
}
```